# how to define function in list comprehension?

Tags: python

Define a function that takes as parameter a list that contains both numbers and strings and return the list containing only the numbers. For example, if I called your function with data([12, 'no data', 13, 14, 'no data')] it should return [12,13,14]?

Thanks,

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match your problem description (which seems to be a copy-paste of an assignment). What, exactly, are you asking? So why would you want to define a function *in* a list comprehension? You don't want a list of functions...

Comment: Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by checking all the elements in your list if they are of type integer.

```
lst = [12, 'no data', 13, 14, 'no data']

def return_int(lst):
    return [i for i in lst if type(i) == int]

numbers = return_int(lst)
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
# This function filters out all elements that are not of type integer
def func(data):
    return [x for x in filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, data)]
```

Comment: If you're using `filter`, you don't need a list comprehension. If you want a list (rather than the iterator you get from `filter`), just pass the iterator to `list` (`list(filter(...))`).

Comment: Thanks Thoothless204:)

Comment: @Blckknght I only used the list comprehension because the title of the question mentioned using a list comprehension, implying that they may be required to implement the function in terms of a list comprehension